# A world outside of gaming? Preposterous! But... it still needs a tag.

Tags: discussion, tags

We've got a few questions that deal with matters of the real world, such as, air quotes, [having](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1372/techniques-to-deal-with-game-addiction) [a](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12620/how-do-i-keep-a-healthy-game-life-balance) [life](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14625/how-do-i-limit-my-gaming). They're currently branded under two separate tags.

- [general-gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-gaming): This is not really different than if we had [gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gaming) instead. This tag, in meaning "gaming stuff that isn't about a specific game", is entirely redundant with the *lack* of specific game tags. Those kinds of questions should be categorized by something that tells you things more important. Like [Ubuntu](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16751/steam-on-ubuntu) or [legal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16763/when-i-buy-a-game-what-do-i-actually-pay-for).

  Plus, those 3 questions are all about *not* gaming, anyway, so the tag doesn't apply. ♪
- [lifestyle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lifestyle): This tag sets a bad precedent, though, because this is kinda opening the doors for "What food should I cook... as a gamer?" type questions. Perhaps it actually gives us something to dwell on, as to dig what elements of these questions make them acceptable on the same lines as health questions.

So, suffice to say, we don't really have a good tag for this scenario. And I have a theoretical train, and by train I mean lavish automobile, to catch, so my mind's not really doing too hot on a good tag. What do you think? How can we properly categorize these questions, and other questions of similar ilk?

Comment: In my opinion, all the ones you linked to in "having a life" are off topic for subjectivity.

Comment: You could post, then, @Strix, that we don't need a tag because any such tag applies to something off-topic.

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure when stackoverflow itself got split into pieces like programmers.SE, cstheory.SE, codegolf.SE, etc. But maybe one day in the distant post-apocalyptic future we will have gamers.SE for these questions.

Comment: @jimmy those sites all cover questions weren't really on topic for SO. Code Golf was allowed, but it never really fit properly.

Comment: I don't see the need to turn down good subjective questions just because Stack Overflow did/does too. I'd rather not see the day when we have gaming.se, gamerec.se, gamers.se, speedruns.se, steam.se, etc. in a triumph of meta topicality migration masturbation that confuses the hell out of those pesky users. If it's videogaming related, if it has answers and not items or unsubstantiated ideas, if it doesn't break windows -- then it's on topic here in my book.

Comment: `[not-gaming-related]`! *:points to npr on Stack Overflow:*

Comment: @badp I think you meant to put that on Strix's answer?

Comment: agree with Strix on this. 99% of this would be either irrelevant to gaming or subjective.

Answer (score 5):

We don't need any such tag because such topics are inherently questions that should be closed anyway.  Most of these questions are either subjective or off-topic as described by the FAQ.

The Steam on Ubuntu one is a legitimate question that has legitimate tags outside the need for some broad-scope tag, and all the other ones in your example are clearly off topic.

Answer (score 3):

I think [lifestyle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lifestyle) is acceptable.

Having such a tag does open the door to lame, subjective questions like "What is your favorite programming language...as a *gamer*?", but I think we can follow [the excellent example of Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) in weeding them out in favor of more valuable, productive ones.

Comment: I'll propose summat similar as I did to badp, but for different reasons - can you think of at least one other example of a constructive, subjective [lifestyle] question that isn't just a constructive rehash of these existing three? The questions I can think of are all of the "for gamers" variety, so if there are no other good ones then I'd prefer a tag that perhaps highlights what scope matter it is that makes these more acceptable.