# [gameplay] and [general-gaming] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

What's the use of the [gameplay](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gameplay) and [general-gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-gaming) tags?

The way I see it [gameplay](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gameplay) could probably be applied to the majority of questions on this site, so it's completely redundant and should be removed.

[general-gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-gaming) may not be redundant but it feels like a synonym of an "off-topic" tag, which is something we don't want... and if we do want, at least let's make it a synonym of something less ambiguous, e.g. [lifestyle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lifestyle) or [real-life](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-life) or *something*.

The way I see it these two tags really need to die, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed, let's add them to the list.

Answer (score 2):

I've been trying to get rid of [general-gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-gaming) [for a while](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1806/a-world-outside-of-gaming-preposterous-but-it-still-needs-a-tag). I have decided to destroy it already, as the only existing questions were old and closed, or not *too* old.

[gameplay](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gameplay) will take some more analysis on how best to replace it. Some instances can be replaced with [game-mechanics](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-mechanics), or perhaps something more explicit if we can think of a good division that makes sense. However, [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3360/world-record-on-nonstop-longest-gameplay-time) only has that one tag. So any suggestions for that, feel free. ♪

Comment: How about [records] or [high-scores]? It better represents what the question is about. Or [gaming-records].

Comment: @Oak Records is more accurate - long gameplay is not a high score in and of itself (and if we have a [high-scores] tag, I think it'd be best used towards questions like "How do I get at least 2,000,000 score in Stage 14b?"). *But*, I'm also hesitant about [records], and I'll see if I can find the corresponding Meta post for it.

Comment: Agreed, it isn't really about scores. [gaming-records] is pretty unambiguous, though, it perfectly represents that question, and I think it could be used for future questions as well (e.g. "who was the best starcraft 2 player during the game's beta?")

Comment: @Oak Your example question is fairly localized (geared to a specific time). There are examples of record questions that we have, but I've been dwelling on my thoughts on the subject [since this posting](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1874/inconsistent-moderation-on-specific-point-in-time). So I will probably hold off on touching that question for now.